# Free subscription, prevent "Share Your Information" box from showing?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to prevent the "Share Your Information" box from showing when the user attempts to subscribe to a free subscription? This app is for my school, and it would look weird if this box pops up besides the fact that I am not allowed to access information about individual users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, thats not possible. There is no way to tell Apple that you don't even want this information, or only partially. You really should file a bug report about this at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) to bring more attention to this problem.